# Any good cross browser webpage compatibility testing addons for firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

Can you suggest some good cross browser compatibility testing addons for firefox that may be useful while webpages developemnt?

Perhaps ones that can show me the view of my webpages in all major browsers by selecting in a single firefox window.

Comment: *Cross browser* for FireFox? On one hand you want it to be cross browser and on the other for Firefox. Weird question.

Comment: @Darin: I guess OP means that an addon that can be installed on Firefox which can be used to see how the current page looks like in other browsers.

Comment: @Marcos: Did you check browsershots.org, though its a online service, it's useful

Comment: This page lists firefox addons for various browsers. http://www.searchenginejournal.com/browsershots/14089/

Comment: @Cybernate: yes you got me right! I havent yet tried out browsershots ; I would try it but I would rather prefer a browser based solution

Comment: @ Cybernate: I guess browsershots wont be helpful while working on localhost as it says *"Browsershots tool makes screenshots of your web page in different browsers.

    When you submit your web address, it will be added to the job queue. A number of distributed computers will open your website in their browser. Then they will make screenshots and upload them to the central server here.
"*

Comment: @Marcos: Indeed, You can't use it for the localhost deployed sites, in which case you have to resort to the addons available for each kind of browser and install them :(

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there is none, and this is why:

Each browser renders based on its edition of the engine upon which it is based. Therefore, to see what a page would look like in IE, you'd have to render in Triton; Mozilla covers firefox; Webkit for Safari and Chrome (though each have differences themselves); etc.

The one way I get around the problem is loading other browsers from safari's `develop` window which offers the chance to open the page in any browser I have installed on my system. This still limits me, however, since I can't run a modern triton browser on OS X (short of installing a windows partition in some manner).

Essentially, browsershots is your only solution short of running all the various browsers.

Comment: browsershots doesnt work with localhost..thus it is no solution for development purposes..

Comment: Sure it is. You don't *have* to develop on localhost; rather, you elect to. But, that being a condition of 'development purposes' in your definition, then my answer is still legitimate from the first line: 'As far as I'm aware, there is none...'

Answer (score 0):

The only one I can think of is [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab/), but that only works on Windows boxes. Might not be quite what you're looking for.